# Cambiar link en función del contenido mostrado en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un pequeño desarrollo de un blog en Laravel 6, este blog tiene un campo categorías, para organizar los post. El filtrado lo tengo resuelto, si pongo x.com/blog/category/{nombre_categoria} las visualizo correctamente. El problema que tengo es que se visualizan desde la misma vista en donde existen 4 links para llamar a las diferentes categorías, el primero seria All (todas), y después las tres categorías que tengo. Lo que necesito es que en función en la categoría que esté se marque como activo ese link.

Mi ruta es la siguiente:

```
Route::get('/blog/category/{slug}', 'ArticleController@category')->name('article.category');
```

Mi controlador donde gestiono la categoria es:

```
public function category($slug)
{
    $category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->pluck('id')->first();
    $articles = Article::where('category_id', $category)->latest()->paginate(6);

    return view('blog.index', compact('articles'));
}
```

Y en mi vista tengo lo siguiente:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav posts__categories-list mr-auto flex-row">
  <li class="post-category active"><a href="#">{{ __('All') }}</a></li>
  <li class="post-category"><a href="">{{ __('Categoría 1') }}</a></li>
  <li class="post-category"><a href="">{{ __('Categoría 2') }}</a></li>
  <li class="post-category"><a href="">{{ __('Categoría 3') }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

En este último no importa poner las rutas a mano o que me lea las categorías de la Base de Datos, ya que estas van a ser fijas no van a cambiar. Me servirían ambas opciones.

Comment: Pero esos links no tienen href.. Cómo haces para que llamen a las diferentes categorías?

Comment: Lo que necesito hacer sería todo esa parte... y poner la función active en función a la categoría seleccionada

Comment: Aún no he podido resolverlo, ¿os surge alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo solucioné añadiendo un operador de comparación en PHP como toda la vida, por si alguien le sirve para salir del paso en un futuro aquí el ejemplo:

```
{{ request()->path() == "category/cybersecurity" ? 'active' : '' }}
```